# Can I add a seperate className for a css file

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using react and I was wondering, I am used to add styling directly in the ClassName.

Let's assume I want to create a seperate css file later to modify the design of the website. For instance this div has a className with the style. What if I want to add a background gradient to it. how do I achieve this from a seperate file. if I add another className it will not work.

```
   <div className="modal-body my-2">
```

Comment: If you add another class and then set the css for that class in a css file, it should work without a problem. What does your css file look like? Did you correctly link it to your html file?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Separate class names with separate files, you must import the other file wherever you want to use the class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably just have to import your css file with the styles you want to add, then add that same class name in the className tag as you would normally do, it should work without problems

```
import 'otherStyle.css'

.otherStyles {
 //Styles here
}

<div class="currentStyle OtherStyle">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```css
.otherClass {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
import CSS from "./path to CSS file";

<div className={`modal-body my-2 ${CSS.otherClass}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import './style1.css';
import './style2.css';

return(
  <div className="first second">
 
  </div>
)

 //style1.css
  .first{
    width : 100%;
  }

 //style2.css
  .second{
    color : black;
  }
```